# After dropping an item on the ground, it doesn't get auto-picked up for a while. How to reset?

Tags: valheim

When I drop an item on the ground from inventory, it will not be auto-picked up even if I have auto-pickup on.

But I've noticed that sometimes it will get auto-picked up anyway. Does this reset after sleeping? Dying? Logging out? Or after a fixed time interval?

It would be great to know how to "reset" this state of items, because sometimes I do want to auto-pickup everything again, but have to do it manually since I don't know how to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't automatically pick up items you dropped.

I don't know when this resets, but I believe you might have to restart the world (or reconnect to the server) to reset the items and be able to pick them back up automatically again.

I believe this is so you don't constantly pick items up that you dropped on purpose.